# Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0024: Could not configure component

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, wildfly

i'm trying to deploy my war in wildfly (JBOSS 8) but i have this error when deploying :

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0024: Could not configure component com.project.UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0048: Could not find default constructor for class com.project.UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl\
```

Here is my `UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl.java` :

```
@WebService(
    serviceName = "UpdateSubscriberInfo",
    portName = "UpdateSubscriberInfoSOAP",
    targetNamespace = "http://myproject.com",
    endpointInterface = "com.project.UpdateSubscriberInfo")
@SchemaValidation
@GuiceManaged(modules = {ProjectWSModule.class})
public class UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl implements UpdateSubscriberInfo {

private final WsUtils wsUtils;
private final UpdateSubscriberInfoWsDataProcessor wsDataProcessor;

@Inject
public UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl(WsUtils wsUtils, UpdateSubscriberInfoWsDataProcessor updateSubscriberInfoWsDataProcessor) {
    this.wsUtils = wsUtils;
    wsDataProcessor = updateSubscriberInfoWsDataProcessor;
}

public UpdateSubscriberInfoResponse updateSubscriberInfo(UpdateSubscriberInfoRequest updateSubscriberInfoRequest) {
    return wsUtils.executeWsProcess(updateSubscriberInfoRequest, ServiceOperation.UPDATE_SUBSCRIBER, null, wsDataProcessor);
}
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is straight-forward.

`Could not find default constructor for class com.project.UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl`

You have used the `@Inject` annotation for an arguments-constructor for `UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl` class but you haven't provided a default non-args costructor.

Please add a default constructor to your class.

```
public UpdateSubscriberInfoImpl() {

}
```